# height of option is not being set

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

In my `CodeIgniter` application I am using following posted code for setting height of each `<option>` inside `<select>` but this code is not working, i.e. the height of `<option>` is not set to `50px`. Please tell what can be the problem?

**Code:**

```
$("option").css("height", "50px");
```

Comment: You cannot reliably change the styling of `option` elements as they are tightly controlled by most browsers. If you want to change the UI of select/option elements you'll need to use a custom library which transforms them to HTML.

Comment: I think the closest you can get to what you want to do is with bootstrap: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/